# hbm2ddl schema export doesn't result in creating entities using Spring Security

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I use Spring Getting Started Content.
I can normally create entites in project accessing-data-mysql and can't create any entity in securing-web-complete.
I made same dependencies and added `application.properties` file like in project accessing-data-mysql

`application.properties` file

```
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sportfacilitydb
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.thymeleaf.mode=LEGACYHTML5
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
```

but nothing happens so I blame spring-security for this.

On console after running app I can notice lines:

```
2017-01-29 12:19:05.511  INFO 9532 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2017-01-29 12:19:05.538  INFO 9532 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2017-01-29 12:19:05.667  INFO 9532 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.11.Final}
2017-01-29 12:19:05.670  INFO 9532 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2017-01-29 12:19:05.676  INFO 9532 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2017-01-29 12:19:05.745  INFO 9532 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
2017-01-29 12:19:06.303  INFO 9532 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
2017-01-29 12:19:06.550  INFO 9532 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
2017-01-29 12:19:06.552  INFO 9532 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000230: Schema export complete
2017-01-29 12:19:06.593  INFO 9532 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
```

So it says schema is created and exported? But why I can't see it in database?
Entity class which I try to create:

`User.java` file

```
package User;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity // This tells Hibernate to make a table out of this class
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    private String email;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }


}
```

This is my `SpringSecurity` configuration file:

`WebSecurityConfig.java`

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/index", "/register", "/aboutus", "/contactus", "/css/**", "/images/**", "/bootstrap/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/index")
                .and()
            .logout()
                .permitAll()
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/index");


    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
    }
}
```

And `Application.java` file:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

I tried to completely delete `application.properties` file, building project returns following:

```
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:
```

> Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE

So I suppose that App is connecting to database

whole `pom.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>gs-securing-web</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.4.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.thymeleaf.extras/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.nekohtml</groupId>
            <artifactId>nekohtml</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.21</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- tag::security[] -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- end::security[] -->

        <!-- JPA Data (We are going to use Repositories, Entities, Hibernate, etc...) -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Use MySQL Connector-J -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**UPDATE**
It was my fatal error actually. According to Spring-boot documentation:

> By default all packages below your main configuration class (the one
>   annotated with @EnableAutoConfiguration or @SpringBootApplication)
>   will be searched.

So I had second parallel package named "User" which was not found by SpringBootApplication Configuration.

Comment: Please post your update as an answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot to add this property in your `application.properties`

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

And dont forget to add this to your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>mysql</groupId>
 <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
 <version>${version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: `spring.datasource.driver-class-name="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"` property does not exist in properly working project from Spring Getting Started Content and adding this to application.properties is making some errors. Also just added whole pom.xml from my project.

Comment: should be without double quotes.. and add explicit version of the mysql-connector and compile scope.. if the property is not enough